# Bind dns zone will not work

Tags: email, dns

THe issue i am having is that i am trying to create a email server but my emails are rejected due to invalid ptr record.

```
$TTL 600
@   IN SOA ns1.first-ns.de. postmaster.robot.first-ns.de. (
    2016012407   ; serial
    14400        ; refresh
    1800         ; retry
    604800       ; expire
    600 )        ; minimum

@                        IN NS      robotns3.second-ns.com.
@                        IN NS      robotns2.second-ns.de.
@                        IN NS      ns1.first-ns.de.

@                        IN A       136.243.6.76
dns1                     IN A       136.243.6.76
dns2                     IN A       136.243.6.76
localhost                IN A       127.0.0.1
mail                     IN A       136.243.6.76
mx1                      IN A       136.243.6.76
mx1.littlefeather.net    IN A       136.243.6.76
www                      IN A       136.243.6.76
76.6.243.136.in-addr.arpa  3600 IN PTR     mx1.littlefeather.net
```

the above zone file is from the master dns from hetzner. I copied this to my dns server as well. the reverse for my ip is 
mx1.littlefeather.net

and my email server hostname is 
mx1.littlefeather.net.

What is wrong with my dns zone file?

Comment: im also ggetting this error on intodns   FAIL: The following nameservers are listed at your nameservers as nameservers for your domain, but are not listed at the parent nameservers (see RFC2181 5.4.1). You need to make sure that these nameservers are working.If they are not working ok, you may have problems! 
ns1.first-ns.de
robotns2.second-ns.de
robotns3.second-ns.com

Comment: With your DNS file none, with your configuration, you are putting a reverse on the forward zone. Reverses go to a separated zone file, and that supposing you are authority to your reverse address. localhost 127.0.0.1 is not supposed to be there. Someone will have to following up with you, leaving for dinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have your reverse and forward zones separate from each other at all times.

Example forward zone, zone "angelsofclockwork.net"

```
$ORIGIN angelsofclockwork.net.
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     angelsofclockwork.net. palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net. (
                        410
                        3H
                        15M
                        1W
                        1D )

                IN      NS      palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net.
palaceredirect  IN      A       10.100.0.1
                IN      AAAA    2001:470:1f19:138::1
myan            IN      A       10.100.0.103
                IN      AAAA    2001:470:1f19:138::4
```

Example reverse zone(s). First one is IPv4, zone "0.100.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA".

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN SOA  @       root (
                                        70              ; serial (d. adams)
                                        3H              ; refresh
                                        15M             ; retry
                                        1W              ; expiry
                                        1D )            ; minimum

                IN      NS      palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net.

1               IN      PTR     palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net.
103             IN      PTR     myan.angelsofclockwork.net.
```

This next one is IPv6, zone "8.3.1.0.9.1.f.1.0.7.4.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA".

```
$TTL    86400
@               IN SOA  @       ns1.angelsofclockwork.net (
                                        411             ; serial (d. adams)
                                        3H              ; refresh
                                        15M             ; retry
                                        1W              ; expiry
                                        1D )            ; minimum

                IN      NS      ns1.angelsofclockwork.net.
                IN      NS      ns2.angelsofclockwork.net.
                IN      NS      palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net.

1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN      PTR     palaceredirect.angelsofclockwork.net.
4.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0 IN      PTR     myan.angelsofclockwork.net.
```

Comment: i had to have my host create the reverse that was the issue I had controll over my forward lookup zones but not reverse.